# How can I improve a little ugly code to load a My.Settings String into a DataGridView ? maybe with LINQ?

Tags: vb.net

I think my code could be much cleaner and smaller, however the code does work. The code retrieves a string saved into My.Settings and loads it into a DataGridView. One of the bad things is I wind up with an extra blank row which I remove after loading the data.

I have tried do loops with and without parsing but I am sure there is a better way...maybe LINQ can improve the code, unfortunately I am not very learned with regard to LINQ.

```
mylistString = My.Settings.saveList
    listArr = mylistString.Split(",")
    f = 0
    g = 0
    For d = 0 To listArr.Count - 1
        If f = 0 Then Dgv0.Rows.Add()
        Dgv0(f, g).Value = listArr(d)
        f = f + 1
        If f > Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            g = g + 1
            f = 0
        End If
    Next
    Dgv0.Rows.RemoveAt(Dgv0.Rows.Count - 1)
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to add an example of the string in My.Settings and the desired result?

Comment: Is your DGV meant to contain just these strings or there's something else in there? Does it have a predefined layout (one or more columns added using its Designer)? Do you want to see the split strings in columns or rows?

Comment: Andrew, the string is as follows: Integer, integer, string, string, string, string, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, Then the second line, which is a repeat of the first line etc. I am getting the desired result. I just believe the code is not as good as it could be.

Comment: Jimi,The code does exactly what it is supposed to do. As you know there are many ways to write code that do the same thing. I was hoping to see a better way to write this code perhaps with the use of LINQ

Comment: This looks like a good question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)